# JQuery autocomplete displays only one item using arrows left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I can't find any information in the documentation or google. This problem doesn't require to show the code to you so I'll show what I mean by these images.

---

1 Step: Going to https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default and type something, for example, "a".
[image]

2 Step: Select the "ActionScript" from the list given above **using arrowDown on the keyboard**:
[image]

3 Step: Press an **arrowLeft button on the keyboard** while "ActionScript" is selected. Poof! The rest of the list is gone except "ActionScript". I have to remove this behavior, so full list is displayed even if the **arrowLeft or arrowRight is pressed**.

Comment: Website bug report there? I can't even go further than providing the input 'a'. Thereafter it falls dead. Bug for sure! Not a question for SO.

Comment: @ZF007 that’s not a bug it’s a behavior.  For a different behavior override the onchange function to keep the float section even pressing the right and left arrows.

Comment: The behavior is not shown on older versions of Firefox. Just figured that one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution!

Simply add this line of code inside an event (keydown, for example):

```
if ($('.ui-menu-item-wrapper').hasClass('ui-state-active') &&
    (e.key == 'ArrowRight' || e.key == 'ArrowLeft')) {
    $(".ui-autocomplete").autocomplete('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press left or right key you have selected ActionScript and it tries to search option in list which have word actionscript that's why it disappeared. Try to search java and then press left or right key list will be there it won't disappear because there is more word starts with java i.e javascript

Comment: I think the OP knows that.

Comment: I mean the list should be like it was all the time. For example, there is a list ["a", "ab", "ac"] and you type "a". When you press an arrow left or right it should be the same. Exactly the same.

Comment: In this list ["a", "ab", "ac"] if you type "a" then list will be the same but if you will select ac then it will disappear

Comment: It shouldn't disappear no matter what.

Comment: with only left and right key it doesn't disappear but if you press down key and then left and right key it disappear. because on down key it select that value. and it functionality of autocomplete. You don't even want to select that value by down key????

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Look at the question :)

Comment: sorry i misunderstood that

Comment: I think that I said everything in the question. After arrowDown, when the user presses az arrowLeft or arrowRight, it should take no effect.